# Как создать вертикальную непрерывную бегущую строку?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

Может кто подскажет, как создать вертикальную бесконечную бегущую строку,которая не будет прерываться. В идеале текст еще и должен исчезать на дне блока (article), хотелось бы, без использования линейного градиента.
Видимо, силами CSS в этом не разобраться.

```css
article {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 65%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.text-animation pre {
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: start;
    letter-spacing: .3rem;
    transform: translatey(-100%);
    animation-name: matrix;
    animation-duration: 30s; 
    animation-timing-function: linear; 
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: none;
    animation-play-state: running; 
    background: none;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    color: black;
    word-break: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* Since CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
  }

  @keyframes matrix {
      0% {
        transform: translatey(-100%);
      }
      50% {
        transform: translatey(0%);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translatey(100%);
      }
  }

  .text-animation pre:nth-child(1) {
    left: -25%;
    font-size: 1.65em;
    animation-delay: 15s;
  }

  .text-animation pre:nth-child(2) {
    left: -25%;
    font-size: 1.65em;
    animation-duration: 10s;
  }
  
.basket {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:34%;
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrap">
<article class="text-animation">
                    <pre>
                    s  
                    s 
                    s 
                    s 
                    s 
                    s 
                    s
                    s
                    s
                    s
                    s
                    s
                    s
                    </pre>
                    <pre>
                    g  
                    g 
                    g 
                    g 
                    g 
                    g 
                    g
                    g 
                    g
                    g
                    g
                    g                        
                    </pre>
                    <pre>
                    r  
                    r 
                    r 
                    r 
                    r 
                    r 
                    r
                    r 
                    r
                    r
                    r
                    r                           
                    </pre>
 </article>
 <div class="basket">
 </div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 5):

Не пугаемся длинного кода - JS для красоты (снова увлёкся))) и не обязателен для решения стартового вопроса.
Собственно сама "бегушка" реализована на CSS (вся "магия" в трёх последних правилах), разметке и позиционировании. Принцип прост, если не сказать примитивен:

- контейнер-обёртка с `position: absolute;` и `overflow: hidden;`;
- контейнер для текста с `position: relative;` на который навешана вся анимация;
- сам текст, который должен повторятся два раза (*важно!* - без пробелов, переводов и отступов).

Т.е. ничего необычного. Дъявол в деталях.

Почему-то самая частая ошибка - это проскролить сразу всю строку на >100%, не думая, что будет в конце строки. А будет скачок анимации к нулевому кадру, где расположено начало строки. Т.о. попытка заменить обрезанный хвост строки осмысленным началом - это неверный путь.
Второй вариант - "добить" пробелами и/или проскролить строку (контейнер), как можно дальше. Тоже неправильный подход, ибо разные размеры шрифтов и т.п.

Здесь алгоритм прост: строку, при вводе один раз дублируем. Теперь строка может начинаться два раза - с начала и с середины. Прокручиваем на 50% строку, т.е. до середины. Далее, уже идёт повтор строки. Вот тут-то и надо переходить к началу анимации, т.е. сбрасывать в начало.
Так организуется циклически повторяющаяся анимация без "прыжков".

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let oSectionWrap = document.querySelector('section.wrap');
  let oRefRunningStr = oSectionWrap.querySelector('article.text-animation');
  let ofragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  let nQ = 3.5; // (0-99) Чем меньше коэффициент, тем больше количество бегущих строк (Осторожно с большим количеством - нагрузка на ЦП и ГП!)
  for (let i = nQ; i < 100; i += nQ) {
    let oNewRunningStr = oRefRunningStr.cloneNode(true);
    // let sRandomStr = 'Своя строка (должна быть больше, чем высота контейнера)'; // Чем длиннее строка, тем быстрее она будет бежать на экране.
    let sRandomStr = fRandomStr();
    oNewRunningStr.style.left = i + '%';
    oNewRunningStr.style.zIndex = (i % 2) ? '100' : '0';
    oNewRunningStr.firstElementChild.innerHTML = sRandomStr + sRandomStr;
    ofragment.appendChild(oNewRunningStr);
  }
  oSectionWrap.appendChild(ofragment);
}

function fRandomStr() {
  let sResultStr = '';
  //let sArrayChars = '01010101010101010101'; // (для символов двоичного кода)
  let sArrayChars = '0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM';
  let nNumbChars = sArrayChars.length - 1;
  let nRandNumbChars = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 75;
  let nPosChar;
  for (let i = 0; i < nRandNumbChars; ++i) {
    nPosChar = Math.floor(Math.random() * nNumbChars);
    sResultStr += sArrayChars.substring(nPosChar, nPosChar + 1);
  }
  return sResultStr;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
  background: url('//www.pcrevue.sk/files/photo/2017-03/25643/6c53a5/C5vo9MV.jpg') #333;
  font: bold 15vh 'Courier New', monospace;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.WrapScroller {
  height: 5em;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
}

.TitleScroller {
  font: 2em/1em 'Arial Black';
  text-shadow: 0 0 45px rgba(56, 253, 44, 0.95);
}

.basket {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #000, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  border: 5px solid black;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 30vh;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 6;
}

.text-animation {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.text-animation div {
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 50s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: matrix;
  animation-play-state: running;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  color: #080;
  font: 5vh 'Courier New', monospace;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(87, 255, 0, 0.93);
  transform: translatey(-100%);
  width: 1em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

@keyframes matrix {
  0% {
    transform: translatey(-50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatey(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="wrap">

  <!--
  Устаревший, но до сих пор работающий тег <marquee> будет 
  всегда актуален. Он как JQuery, но только в один тег :-)
  -->
  <marquee class="WrapScroller" behavior="alternate" direction="down" scrollamount="1" scrolldelay="70" truespeed>
    <marquee class="TitleScroller" behavior="alternate" scrollamount="1" scrolldelay="60" truespeed>MATRIX</marquee>
  </marquee>
  <!-- end marquee -->

  <div class="basket"> </div>
  <article class="text-animation">
    <div>Может кто подскажет,как создать вертикальную бесконечную бегущую строку,которая не будет прерываться.В идеале текс еще и должен исчезать на дне блока (article),вот только бы, без использования линейного градиента. Видимо,силами CSS в этом не разобраться.Может
      кто подскажет,как создать вертикальную бесконечную бегущую строку,которая не будет прерываться.В идеале текс еще и должен исчезать на дне блока (article),вот только бы, без использования линейного градиента. Видимо,силами CSS в этом не разобраться.</div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Как я уже написал выше, основная масса кода для наглядности, и может быть сокращена в два-три раза. В коде есть пояснения по основным блокам и параметрам. Но, если возникнут вопросы - комментируйте.

P.S. Ах, да... По в второму вопросу: пока не придумали градиент для текста, который бы не взаимодействовал с background-ом. Т.ч. плавное исчезновение только при наложении фона с градиентом...