# Бегущая строка анимация

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть бегущая строка

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#quotes-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 51px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#quotes {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Tahoma";
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 100%;
  margin: 0;
  animation: scroll 30s infinite linear;
}

#quotes li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
  width: 210px;
}

#quotes li span {
  margin: 0 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #aab9d1;
}

#quotes li span:nth-child(odd) {
  position: relative;
}

#quotes li span:nth-child(odd):after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -14px;
  content: "|";
}

#quotes li.up span:nth-child(odd) {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#quotes li.up span {
  color: #00ca51;
}

#quotes li.up span:nth-child(odd):before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -14px;
  top: 6px;
  content: ' ';
  border-width: 0 5px 9px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #00ca51 transparent;
}

#quotes li.down span:nth-child(odd) {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#quotes li.down span {
  color: #f12424;
}

#quotes li.down span:nth-child(odd):before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -14px;
  top: 6px;
  content: ' ';
  border-width: 9px 5px 0 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f12424 transparent;
}

#quotes li.round span:nth-child(odd) {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#quotes li.round span:nth-child(odd):before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -14px;
  top: 7px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #aab9d1;
  content: ' ';
}

-webkit-keyframes scroll 0% {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0)
}

-webkit-keyframes scroll 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transform: translate(-100%, 0)
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    transform: translate(-100%, 0)
  }
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    transform: translate(-100%, 0)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="quotes-container">
  <ul id="quotes">
    <li id="Ripple" class="down">Ripple<span id="bidRipple">0.6297</span><span id="askRipple">0.6314</span></li>
    <li id="Litecoin" class="round">Litecoin<span id="bidLitecoin">159.06</span><span id="askLitecoin">161.25</span></li>
    <li id="Ethereum" class="up">Ethereum<span id="bidEthereum">518.4</span><span id="askEthereum">522.21</span></li>
    <li id="USDCHF" class="round">USDCHF<span id="bidUSDCHF">0.9467</span><span id="askUSDCHF">0.9468</span></li>
    <li id="USDJPY" class="round">USDJPY<span id="bidUSDJPY">104.903</span><span id="askUSDJPY">104.911</span></li>
    <li id="EURCAD" class="round">EURCAD<span id="bidEURCAD">1.59199</span><span id="askEURCAD">1.592</span></li>
    <li id="Dash" class="round">Dash<span id="bidDash">407.87</span><span id="askDash">410.39</span></li>
    <li id="AUDUSD" class="round">AUDUSD<span id="bidAUDUSD">0.77241</span><span id="askAUDUSD">0.77249</span></li>
    <li id="Bitcoin" class="round">Bitcoin<span id="bidBitcoin">8436</span><span id="askBitcoin">8456.1</span></li>
    <li id="NZDUSD" class="round">NZDUSD<span id="bidNZDUSD">0.72707</span><span id="askNZDUSD">0.72717</span></li>
    <li id="EURUSD" class="round">EURUSD<span id="bidEURUSD">1.23742</span><span id="askEURUSD">1.23762</span></li>
    <li id="AUDCAD" class="round">AUDCAD<span id="bidAUDCAD">0.9937</span><span id="askAUDCAD">0.9942</span></li>
    <li id="GBPUSD" class="round">GBPUSD<span id="bidGBPUSD">1.41651</span><span id="askGBPUSD">1.41656</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Никак не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы не было такого большого промежутка между заходом за пределы экрана и выходом, т.е. сделать так, чтобы строка еще до конца не ушла за пределы экрана слева, а справа уже появляется.

И еще: бывает, что анимация начинает притормаживать через некоторое время. Как быть с этим?

Спасибо!

Comment: Самый простой вариант использовать два блока #quotes друг за другом на необходимом расстоянии, и просто в нужный вам момент запускать второй. Что касается подтормаживаний браузер сам оптимизирует частоту кадров при хорошей графической карте и оптимизации системы никаких подтормаживайний не будет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как создать вертикальную непрерывную бегущую строку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/751842/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%89%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 5):

С подходом — "каждому элементу свой ID" — я не согласен и хотел бы пояснить.

ID — это уникальный идентификатор для конкретного элемента. Ключевое слово здесь — "уникальный" и оно подразумевает, что такой ID будет только один на странице. При использовании данного атрибута, теряется "гибкость" в манипуляциях с элементами (к примеру, клонирование или создание элемента с таким же значением ID). Появление элементов с одинаковым идентификатором может привести к непредсказуемым результатам — где-то может обрабатываться только первый элемент, а где-то код может оказаться полностью неработоспособным. Поэтому, применение ID должно быть там, где это действительно оправданно и/или необходимо.

В большинстве случаев, можно и нужно использовать другие способы доступа к элементам:

- по пользовательским атрибутам (`data-attr`);
- по именам классов и другим CSS-селекторам, с помощью `querySelector`;
- по дочерним элементам, используя `children[]`.

В коде из вопроса, значения ID вложенных элементов отличаются от родительского идентификатора, только префиксами (*bid* и *ask*) и более никакой полезной нагрузки не несут. При этом, структура всех пунктов одинакова. В этом случае, меняем атрибут `id` на пользовательский атрибут `data-curr`, а далее, обращаемся к потомкам с помощью `children[n]`, т.к. эти элементы всегда стоят в одном и том же порядке. Таким образом, можно будет клонировать и создавать элементы, не боясь дублирования ID.

Я уже описывал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/877694/265406) алгоритм и самую распространённую ошибку "бегущей строки" с помощью `animation`, т.ч. повторяться не буду. Добавлю только, что для правильной работы данного подхода, есть обязательное условие - ширина (высота, для вертикальной строки) скроллируемого элемента должна быть вдвое больше максимальной ширины (высоты) контейнера, в котором элемент прокручивается.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var oQuotes = document.querySelector('#quotes-container ul.quotes');

  /* Функция дублирования пунктов */
  function fDoublingQuotes() {
    let nElem = oQuotes.children.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < nElem; i++) {
      oQuotes.appendChild(oQuotes.children[i].cloneNode(true));
    }
    oQuotes.style.animationDuration = '1s,' + (nElem * 2) + 's';
  }

  /* Функция для изменения значений пунктов */
  function fSetQuote(sId, sClass, sBid, sAsk) {
    let aQuotes = oQuotes.querySelectorAll('li[data-curr="' + sId + '"]');
    aQuotes.forEach(function(item) {
      item.className = sClass || item.className;
      item.children[0].innerText = sBid || item.children[0].innerText;
      item.children[1].innerText = sAsk || item.children[1].innerText;
    });
  }

  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    fSetQuote('Ripple', '', '0', '1');
  });

  fDoublingQuotes();
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#quotes-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 51px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#quotes-container:before,
#quotes-container:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 51px;
  width: 25px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0));
}
#quotes-container:after {
  right: 0;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.quotes {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0; /* Важно! */
  animation: begin 1s ease forwards, scroll 30s linear 1s infinite;
}

.quotes li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em 40px 1em 0;
  font: bold 16px 'Tahoma';
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.quotes li span {
  margin: 0 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #aab9d1;
}

.quotes li span:nth-child(odd) {
  position: relative;
}

.quotes li span:nth-child(odd):after {
  content: '|';
  position: absolute;
  right: -14px;
  top: -1;
}

.quotes li.up span:nth-child(odd),
.quotes li.down span:nth-child(odd),
.quotes li.round span:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.quotes li.round span:nth-child(odd):before {
  content: '⚫';
  position: absolute;
  left: -16px;
  top: 0px;
}

.quotes li.up span {
  color: #00ca51;
}
.quotes li.up span:nth-child(odd):before {
  content: '▲';
  position: absolute;
  left: -18px;
  top: 1px;
}

.quotes li.down span {
  color: #f12424;
}
.quotes li.down span:nth-child(odd):before {
  content: '▼';
  position: absolute;
  left: -18px;
  top: 1px;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-50%); }
}
@keyframes begin {
  0% { transform: scaleY(0); }
  100% { transform: scaleY(1); }
}
```

```html
<div id="quotes-container">
  <ul class="quotes">
    <li data-curr="Ripple" class="down">Ripple<span>0.6297</span><span>0.6314</span></li>
    <li data-curr="Litecoin" class="round">Litecoin<span>159.06</span><span>161.25</span></li>
    <li data-curr="Ethereum" class="up">Ethereum<span>518.4</span><span>522.21</span></li>
    <li data-curr="USDCHF" class="round">USDCHF<span>0.9467</span><span>0.9468</span></li>
    <li data-curr="USDJPY" class="round">USDJPY<span>104.903</span><span>104.911</span></li>
    <li data-curr="EURCAD" class="round">EURCAD<span>1.59199</span><span>1.592</span></li>
    <li data-curr="Dash" class="round">Dash<span>407.87</span><span>410.39</span></li>
    <li data-curr="AUDUSD" class="round">AUDUSD<span>0.77241</span><span>0.77249</span></li>
    <li data-curr="Bitcoin" class="round">Bitcoin<span>8436</span><span>8456.1</span></li>
    <li data-curr="NZDUSD" class="round">NZDUSD<span>0.72707</span><span>0.72717</span></li>
    <li data-curr="EURUSD" class="round">EURUSD<span>1.23742</span><span>1.23762</span></li>
    <li data-curr="AUDCAD" class="round">AUDCAD<span>0.9937</span><span>0.9942</span></li>
    <li data-curr="GBPUSD" class="round">GBPUSD<span>1.41651</span><span>1.41656</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button>Изменить "Ripple"</button>
```

*Если что-то будет непонятно по коду и логике, то спрашиваем в комментариях - отвечу или дополню ответ.*

Comment: Super...........

Comment: @Air ну надо же контент для ruSO генерить)) Не всё ж мне минусы собирать)

Comment: Я как вопрос прочитал сразу мысль пришла реализовать как у тя... Ну и немного прокрутив вниз обнаружил твой ответ)))

Comment: Кстати, я бы реализовал бы без псевда-элементов. просто можно было бы клонировать родителя, и кода было бы меньше и если вдруг что то надо было бы изменять, было бы на много легче.

Comment: @Air я и так исходник изрядно покромсал)) А так, конечно же, есть что пригладить ещё.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант ...

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
  width: 200%;
  animation: scroll 10s infinite linear;
}

li {
  text-align:center;
  background:#fbfbfb;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -110%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
    <li>item4</li>
    <li>item5</li>
    <li>item6</li>
    <li>item7</li>
    <li>item8</li>
    <li>item9</li>
    <li>item10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

либо такой вариант : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/OvxxXP?editors=1100