# Требуется зациклить анимацию

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация, animate, event-loop

Столкнулся с проблемой зацикливания анимация.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы сделать бегущую строку (настоящую), и для этого требуется сделать перестановку элементов, на данный момент это есть, но теперь требуется зациклить весь этот процесс.

Воспроизвести проблему можно сразу при запуске, после красной строки должно быть продолжение.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.uspSlider = function(options) {

    var settings = $.extend({
      'widthSliderResize': 1000,
      'countElements': 3,
      'tagDOM': 'li',
      'showClassAppendAndPrepend': true,
      'showDebugElements': true,
      'duration': 7000,
      'easing': 'linear'
    }, options);

    var mainContainer = this;

    var sliderController = {
      items: [],
      itemsCloned: {
        append: [],
        prepend: []
      },
      width: 0,
      fullWidth: 0,
      fullWidthWithMargin: 0,
      countElements: settings['countElements'],
      tagDOM: settings['tagDOM'],
      margin: {
        container: '0 0 0 0',
        element: '0 10px 0 0',
        _left: 0,
        _right: 10,
        lastChildElement: false
      }
    };

    var methods = {
      _init: function() {

        $(sliderController.tagDOM, mainContainer).each(function() {
          sliderController.items.push($(this));
          sliderController.width += $(this).outerWidth(true);
        });

        var sliderItemsLength = sliderController.items.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < sliderItemsLength; i++) {
          var j = sliderItemsLength - (i + 1);
          sliderController.items[i].clone().addClass('cloned append').appendTo(mainContainer);
          sliderController.items[j].clone().addClass('cloned prepend').prependTo(mainContainer);
        }

        var sliderContainerAllElemetsLength = sliderController.countElements * sliderController.countElements;

        $(sliderController.tagDOM, mainContainer).each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).hasClass('append')) {
            sliderController.itemsCloned.append.push($(this));
          } else if ($(this).hasClass('prepend')) {
            sliderController.itemsCloned.prepend.push($(this));
          }

          if (!settings['showClassAppendAndPrepend']) {
            $(this).removeClass('append prepend');
          }

          if (index < sliderContainerAllElemetsLength - 1 && !sliderController.margin.lastChildElement) {
            $(this).css('margin', sliderController.margin.element);
          }
        });

        var widthWithMargin = (sliderContainerAllElemetsLength * (sliderController.margin._right + sliderController.margin._left));

        sliderController.fullWidth = ((sliderController.width * sliderController.countElements) + widthWithMargin);

        sliderController.fullWidthWithMargin = sliderController.fullWidth + widthWithMargin;

        mainContainer.width(sliderController.fullWidth);

        if (settings['showDebugElements']) {
          console.table(sliderController);
        }

        methods.uspBlockController();
      },
      _destroy: function() {
        console.log('Destroy here!');
      },
      uspBlockController: function() {
        var windowInnerWidth = window.innerWidth;

        var controlClonedSliderElements = function(value) {
          $(sliderController.tagDOM, mainContainer).each(function(index) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('cloned')) {
              value ? $(this).removeClass('cloned-disable') : $(this).addClass('cloned-disable');
            }
          });
        }

        if (windowInnerWidth < settings['widthSliderResize']) {
          mainContainer.addClass('activeMobileUSP')

          if (sliderController.items.length <= 0) {
            methods._init();
          }

          controlClonedSliderElements(true);

          mainContainer.width(sliderController.fullWidth);

          var count = 1
          tmpCount = 1,
            itemsPositionLeft = [];

          var animated = function(element) {
            element.animate({
              uspWidth: sliderController.fullWidth
            }, {
              step: function(widthForFirstAnimate, fx) {

                $(this).css('-webkit-transform', "translate(" + -widthForFirstAnimate + "px, 0)");

                var checkedAnimate = function() {
                  if (mainContainer.find(sliderController.tagDOM + ':nth-child(' + count + ')').is(':offscreen')) {

                    var thisElement = mainContainer.find(sliderController.tagDOM + ':nth-child(' + count + ')');

                    itemsPositionLeft.push(widthForFirstAnimate);

                    function tmpAnimate(tmpElement) {

                      console.log(tmpElement);

                      tmpElement.stop(true, false);

                      tmpElement.animate({
                        uspWidth: sliderController.fullWidth + itemsPositionLeft[tmpElement.index()]
                      }, {
                        start: function() {
                          console.log(tmpElement.index());

                          tmpCount++;

                          if (tmpCount > (sliderController.countElements * sliderController.countElements)) {
                            tmpCount = 1;
                          }
                        },
                        step: function(widthForSecondAnimate, fx) {
                          var stepVariable = 40; // Переменная которая отвечает за прижимание к левому краю первоначального animate

                          $(this).find('a').css("color", "red");

                          $(this).css("-webkit-transform", "translate(" + (-widthForSecondAnimate + sliderController.fullWidth - stepVariable) + "px, 0)");

                          if ($(this).is(':offscreen') && ($(this).index() + 1) == tmpCount) {

                            // Тому элементу, который скрылся за левую часть экрана, обновляем анимацию.

                            tmpAnimate(mainContainer.find(sliderController.tagDOM + ':nth-child(' + tmpCount + ')'));

                          }
                        },
                        duration: settings['duration'],
                        easing: settings['easing']
                      });
                    };

                    count++;

                    if (count > (sliderController.countElements * sliderController.countElements)) {
                      count = 1;
                    }

                    tmpAnimate(thisElement);
                  }
                }

                checkedAnimate();
              },
              duration: settings['duration'],
              easing: settings['easing']
            });
          };

          animated(mainContainer.find(sliderController.tagDOM));

        } else if (windowInnerWidth > settings['widthSliderResize'] &&
          mainContainer.hasClass('activeMobileUSP')) {
          mainContainer.removeClass('activeMobileUSP');

          controlClonedSliderElements(false);

          mainContainer.find(sliderController.tagDOM).stop(true, true).animate({
            uspWidth: 0
          }).css('-webkit-transform', "translate(0, 0)").width('auto');

          mainContainer.width('auto');
        }
      }
    }

    $(window).resize(function() {
      methods.uspBlockController();
    });

    $.expr.filters.offscreen = function(el) {
      var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
      return (
        (rect.x + rect.width) < 0 ||
        (rect.y + rect.height) < 0 ||
        (rect.x > window.innerWidth || rect.y > window.innerHeight)
      );
    };

    methods.uspBlockController();
  };

  $('.usp-block-container').find('.usp-block-details').uspSlider({
    'widthSliderResize': 486,
    'showClassAppendAndPrepend': true,
    'showDebugElements': false
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.usp-block-container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.usp-block-details {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.usp-block-details .item {
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.usp-block-details .item a {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Consolas', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.usp-block-details .item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}


/* Style for usp-controller */

.cloned-disable {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<h1>USP loop</h1>
<div class="usp-block-container">
  <ul class="usp-block-details">
    <li class="item"><a href="">First</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="">Second</a></li>
    <li class="item"><a href="">Third</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Прошу обратить внимание на строку 211. 
Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Здесь не видно номер строк, к сожалению :)

Comment: // Тому элементу, который скрылся за левую часть экрана, обновляем анимацию.

Да, обратите внимание на данный комментарий, это и есть наша строка)

Comment: А почему нельзя использовать CSS? Например https://codepen.io/lewismcarey/pen/GJZVoG

Comment: Очень неплохо, но она работает на совсем так как надо. Бегущая строка - это когда без пробелов, друг за другом, идут элементы, а в данном примере, который скинули Вы, элементы сначала уходят за левую сторону, а после снова воспроизводятся.

Comment: О какой анимации идет речь? Вопрос должен содержать минимальный самодостаточный воспроизводимый пример, суть описания проблемы и желаемый конечный результат.

Comment: Анимация типа "Бегущая строка". Воспроизвести пример нужно на определенном размере, в нашем случае, когда размер экрана менее 486 px. В итоге выполнения задания, мы должны получить бегущую строку. Данный параметр отвечает за размер, при котором будет стартовать работа скрипта 'widthSliderResize': 486.

Comment: Если это просто меню должно зациклиться, то лучше уж `css` выше вполне справедливо отметил @XelaNimed

Comment: Для этих задач уже имеется много готовых решений... По-английски бегущая строка - "ticker". Загуглите "js ticker"...

Comment: 1) С помощью CSS, получится не совсем то, что мне требуется. 
2) Примеров бегущей строки очень много, и я еще посижу поищу, возможно найду или полностью адекватно рабочий скрипт, или решение моей задачи, но все что я уже перелопатил, к сожалению совершенно не подходит. (И прежде чем сюда писать, я много гуглил)

Comment: @DmitryShmaliuk "бегушки" без пробелов: 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907355/265406 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/877694/265406

Comment: @UModeL, первый пример "прыгает", второй никак образом не относится к текущему заданию, но спасибо за примеры, второй довольно интересный.